# Marking for Operating Tempature Range on Diode's data sheet?

Tags: diodes, datasheet, markings

My diode is:

> VISHAY GENERAL SEMICONDUCTOR 1N4004-E3
>
> Diode
>
> Diode Type:Standard Recovery;
>   Repetitive Reverse Voltage Max,
>   Vrrm:400V; Forward Current, If(AV):1A;
>   Forward Voltage Max, VF:1.1V; Forward
>   Surge Current Max, Ifsm:30A; Operating
>   Temperature Ran 78K2120;

[Source, please, search for 78K2120.](http://at.farnell.com/jsp/search/browse.jsp;jsessionid=YTEEQOAO1ZSPQCQLCIPJMMQ?N=0&Ntk=gensearch_002&Ntt=1N4004&Ntx=mode+matchallpartial&suggestions=false&ref=globalsearch&_requestid=660188)

**Questions**

1. What does "78K2120" mean?
2. According to the new reply, it is an identifier but what does it mean? Why is it chosen? Does it contain some information except being a random identifier?
3. Is there some standard, seen too many manufacturers just throwing similar lines but with different meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Newark and their answer is: "Our part# does not mean anything in relation to the specs on the manufacturer part.". So it is apparently about book-keeping.

Comment: yes, a part number is for book keeping. They are about finding parts in stock, they have no bearing on function of the device. a well design system has some connection between device and assigned part number, like the 78k might mean it is a diode, but that is it.

Comment: cannot understand down-vote, have to label question as beginner. The thing "78K2120" is similar to smallCaps' markings such as "104 K5K", "154 C1K", "104K X7R50" and probably many other markings -- easy for beginners to overlook!

Answer (score 4):

78K2120 is the Newark product code for that diode.

http://www.newark.com/vishay-general-semiconductor/1n4004-e3/diode/dp/78K2120?Ntt=78K2120

Google FTW.

That diode's temperature range is -50~+150 degrees celsius. Data sheet: http://www.vishay.com/doc?88503; Farnell Australia (au.farnell.com) part number 1421919.

Comment: These are the same numbers I found.

Comment: it is still open what does it mean and why is it chosen? -- cannot believe it is just a random identifier

Comment: the 78k probably is a number used for all diodes, but yes, it is a random identifier. It is based on some internal system, but it is random as far as you will ever know and does not correlate to device function.

Comment: My name Kortuk identifies me, it does not let you know how awesome I am unless you have used a kortuk before and found out that, on the whole, people with the name kortuk are winners.